# Moving elements of a div to the right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple parent div element containing multiple child div elements. When the page is loaded, these div elements are displayed on the left. I would like to display these items on the right. How can I achieve this?

Currently, my page elements look like this:
[image: Normal]

If I try style="float:right", I am getting compressed elements:
[image: Compressed]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-wrap:none; width:11%">
        <label>Requests Per Page: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="text-wrap:none">
        <select id="RecordsPerPage">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="150">150</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>
            <option value="250">250</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="text-wrap:none">
        Go to Page #:
        <input type="number" id="UserPageNumber" min="1" size="5" style="width:50px;" value="1" max="87">
        of <span id="spTotalPages">87</span>
        <button id="btnPage" onclick="handlePaging();">GO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using the `position: relative; right:0;` strategy?

Comment: It looks like you are using [Boostrap v3's Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid). If so, you can add an offset to your first column, equal to the leftover space you want to create. Assuming you have a 12 column grid, you are using 2 + 1 + 3 = **6** columns, so you want an offset of 12 - 6 = **6**. So on your first `col-md-2` element, add the class `col-md-offset-6`.

Answer (score 0):

Add class **justify-content-end**  to row element

```
<div class="row align-items-end">
```

I also recomend using bootstrap utility classes instead of inline styles. Here is your example - little adjusted: https://www.bootply.com/k7mrP9fHPz

Assumed you are using current version of Boostrap - v4